# How to verify the status of the buttons using MonkeyTalk command

Tags: monkeytalk

Anyone please tell me the command to verify whether the option is enabled or disabled using Monkey-talk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at the .enabled property is true or false.  Here is an example:

```
Button login_button Verify 1 .enabled 
Button login_button Verify 0 .enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Search for the button name in the component tree and see the state whether it is visible / hidden.
2. If there is a button named "LOGIN", the mt command, "Button LOGIN Verify" will check whether LOGIN button is visible on the screen. If it is visible on the screen, it returns "Completed Script Playback - OK".
   If LOGIN button is hidden or not available in the activity, then returns, "FAILURE: Unable to find Button(LOGIN)".

Comment: Yes we can verify that the button is visible on the screen or not, but how can we verify the button is enabled or not. For example in Login screen there is "Login" button, it should be enabled only after entering the username and password in the fields, otherwise it should be disabled..like it should be present in the screen but it should be grayed out.